# Perl Escape::HTML function doesn't escape #?

Tags: perl, html-escape-characters

Managed to narrow the code down a lot more:

http://pastebin.com/J40Atm9m

Sorry to be a pain but I really thought I had it cracked by using `uri_escape` in the `GetQueryString` subroutine but now I'm really out of ideas otherwise I wouldn't ask.

Any insights are much appreciated.

Martin

Comment: thanks for the help, I think I need to create a new question as the code posted wasn't ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML::Escape isn't *supposed* to escape "#" because "#" isn't unsafe for HTML.The problem is that you're not URI-escaping your data before you're putting it into a URI; use [URI::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/URI%3a%3aEscape) for that.

Answer (score 4):

That is a **lot** of code. A reduced test case would be helpful.

Rather than read all of it, I'm going to assume that this is what you are doing:

1. You get raw data
2. You put raw data in a URI
3. You encode the URI for HTML
4. You put the encoded URI in the HTML

If so, then what you missed is this:

You need to [encode the data for the URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aEscape).